# Subclipse plugin doesn't work in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

even though there was no error when installing Subclipse in Eclipse. I won't see the SVN perspective at all?
I have tried with "Eclipse Classic 3.5.1" and with "Eclipse for PHP Developers".
After downloading and unzipping the packages I used Eclipse's "Install Software" mechanism to install Subclipse 1.6.x. I followed the steps described here: http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/jreality/mediawiki/index.php/Subclipse_installation_in_eclipse_galileo.

But after Eclipse re-starts I don't get any SVN Repository perspective? I have tried to un-install/re-install all the software components many times now. Finally after 3 hours of trying I am giving up. Does anyone have any hint what I am missing?

Thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I use Windows 7 64 bits OS. I clean read-only flag of eclipse folder in C:\Program Files (x86) and give full access right to all users on my PC. I reinstalled it from update site and it works.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't appear to cope well with permissions on Windows. Setting security permissions for "All users" to "Allow" for all operations on the Eclipse installation directory in Program Files resolved a similar problem with Subversive for me.

Comment: Note that you may have to run Eclipse as an administrator for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug with subclipse: http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=992

*EDIT* For anyone keeping track of this, it looks like Eclipse Helios SR1 may have fixed the issue.  I haven't tested it myself yet, but by the sounds of the discussion at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322929 it should now be working.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same issue with Ubuntu. It turned out to be permissions. Once I gave write permissions to everywhere in my eclipse installation and then reinstalled subclipse, its views and so forth appeared, just like magic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are looking for. But after installing the Subclipse plugin, you should have a new entry in the File | New | Project dialog. Something along the lines of "Checkout project from SVN"

Then when you hit continue, you can enter your SVN repository details, check the branch you are interested in, etc. After checking out a project, you can right click on it and go to the "Team" submenu to get the features provided by Subclipse like check in code, diff, merge, etc.

Comment: Can you check the link I posted above? What I want to have is my own SVN Repository...

Comment: I don't have such an entry "Checkout project from SVN".

Comment: Assuming you installed Subclipse correctly, run Eclipse with the -clean argument to make it clear your cache data. Then you should have the checkout project from SVN option, which should be under the SVN project type.

Comment: What do I run with -clean argument? Eclipse?
So "eclipse.exe -clean"? It doesn't work, I still don't see anything named SVN. There were no installation errors. As I already wrote above, I downloaded Eclipse and simply un-zipped it so I am using it out-of-the-box.

Comment: Check this image: http://www.dokeos.com/wiki/images/2/29/Eclipse-svn-02.jpg If you don't see that, then Subclipse is not correctly installed. I suggest you install it again from Subclipse update site http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x I installed it as I type this and it works flawlessly.

Comment: As I already wrote... I've been trying to install this for 3 hours now... I downloaded and used everything out-of-the-box. No errors on installation. In the image that you linked above I don't see any SVN folder and I don't see it in the perspective selection window (http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/jreality/mediawiki/index.php/Image:Subclipse9.png) either.

Comment: What do you mean by in the image I linked above you don't see any SVN folder? Come on! It's right there, it's even the selected option!

Comment: You know what - if you can't help me then simply don't write back. I don't need answers implying that I am stupid! The image is not from my installation but from the installation description which I followed. If you would have read my post carefully you would have noticed. On my own installation I don't see anything with "SVN".

Comment: I never implied you are stupid, I'm just trying to help. In your comment you clearly stated that in the image I linked you don't see any SVN folder, which there is. I read your question clearly and I'm aware that what you linked is not your installation.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem too.  I installed both Subclipse and GWT/GAE plugins and couldn't find any evidence of them after installation.

I'm on Windows 7 and had installed Eclipse 3.5 SR2 into C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse-3.5.  I also put my workspace in C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse-3.5\workspace.  When I was checking things I noticed there was a lock icon on the C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse-3.5\workspace.

I reinstalled Eclipse to C:\dev\eclipse and the workspace to C:\dev\eclipse\workspace.  After that the installation of the plugins went without a hitch and I could see the SVN Repository Exploring perspective (no idea why some of the other posters claim this perspective doesn't exist).  I suspect it was some sort of permissions problem on the directories.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check and see if the whole thing was installed correctly is to go to the SVN Repositories view. Go to Window -> Show View -> Other, and then search for SVN. If you see a bunch of SVN views like "Repositories," Subclipse is installed.

Comment: I don't have any SVN Repository view... that's my point. There was no exception that Subclipse was not successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem due to some kind of incompatibility between Subclipse and Android ADT plugins. [One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350510) suggested [yoxos](http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/yoxos-ondemand/) which gives you all your eclipse plugins from one central repository.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I work on Linux, and when I installed eclipse in `/usr/local/eclipse`, Subclipse did not show up. The solution was to install Eclipse locally, e.g. in `/home/user/eclipse`. Now Subclipse (and other plugins too) worked!

Edit: guess it could be the same on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to some incompatibilities between the packages of subclipse and the gwt 2.x plugin and android... as this started happen to me after I upgrade to v 2.0 of gwt back in the day.

The same issue repeats both on Mac and Windows... and it seems no fix has been released.

Now the only way I've found to move on with my work is to remove subclipse and install the latest subversive plugin instead.

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/

I know this ain't subclipse but it works very similar and no issues with gwt nor android plugins.

it worked for me and so I hope it works for you in the mean time.

cheers,

G.

Comment: just in case the version I installed was added from 

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/ 

which as of now it's the latest stable version.