# Why can't Subclipse coexist with Android Developer Tools (ADT) plug-in?

Tags: android, eclipse, subclipse, adt

On a fresh install of Eclipse:

- **Eclipse** - 3.52 Galileo-SR2-win32
- **Java Version** - JRE 6 (update 18)
- **Host OS** - Windows 7 (32-bit)

...if I install both of the following plug-ins (in any order), they *both stop working*.

- **Android Developer Tools plug-in** - ADT 0.9.5 *(recommended for Eclipse 3.5x)*
- **Subclipse plug-in** - 1.6.x *(recommended for Eclipse 3.5x)*

The error log shows nothing, but all traces of ADT and Subclipse are gone from the menus, the toolbar, the Preferences dialog, etc.

I've progressively backtracked until I was installing completely from scratch (including deleting my workspace and .eclipse folder). I even tried increasing initial and maximum Java heap size for Eclipse. No joy.

Googling for this issue results in a number of posts from people having similar or identical problems. Unfortunately, no one seems to have an answer.

Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a platform like [yoxos](http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/yoxos-ondemand/) which gives you all your eclipse plugins from one central repository. Thereby everything fits together.

Btw... i use subversive in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not the latest and greatest but have you tried to get these plugins working using Eclipse Ganymede?

I use Ganymede (3.4.2) with ADT (0.9.5) and Subclipse (1.6.5) without any issues on win7 pro 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using both side by side no issues:

subclipse 1.6
android developer plugin 0.9.9
eclipse 3.6.1