# Subclipse installed but no features appear in Eclipse 4.2 Juno

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, eclipse-juno

I've installed Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) and am trying to get Subclipse to work. I used the 1.8.x update site:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

Installing is no problem. Here's what it looks like installed:

[image]

However, even though it's installed, there's no sign of it in Eclipse anywhere other than the page of packages above. No SVN perspectives, nothing in the preferences menu, nothing in the context menu under "Team...", no SVN annotations on my projects.

I've had this problem with earlier versions of Eclipse when using Subclipse, but it usually went away after I uninstall all of Subclipse and then reinstall it. However, multiple attempts to do that didn't fix this situation, so I'm not sure what is going on.

As you can see, there is very little installed - just m2e and subclipse.

**EDIT: I realized that I had two different versions of m2e installed - the one that came with eclipse and the version I installed from the update URL. When I removed the one I installed, Subclipse started working again.** Clearly some strange conflict between the different plugins caused this problem. However, I'm not sure what is the best way to fix situations like this in the future - where are the error and/or other logs to check to find out when something has likely broken?

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be some kind of Eclipse bug as it owns the install process.  Stuff like showing items in the list of Perspectives or Views or Preferences only requires Eclipse to parse the plugin.xml.  The fact that Eclipse is not showing any of those items means something is wrong in Eclipse.  Maybe some kind of filesystem permission issue somewhere?

Have you checked the Eclipse error log to see if anything was logged?

Comment: I discovered that I had m2e installed over an already-included version, and after removing that, Subclipse was fixed. I have no idea how to find and fix these conflicts in a principled way. Which error log should I look for?

Comment: It is the file named ".log" in your workspace/.metadata folder.  However, there is an Eclipse view called "Error Log" that exists in the "General" grouping.  If you have that view installed you can also see stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a problem of write permission in your eclipse installation folder.
Uninstall your feature, set full write access to your installation folder, restart eclipse and install again. Should work now.
This is already discussed here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276932/subclipse-plugin-doesnt-work-in-eclipse). Or have a look here: [subclipse thread](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1046&dsMessageId=2448057).